# Can I find out during debugging which field is public, which is private, which is protected?

Tags: xdebug

I apologize in advance if the question is stupid, I'm newbie. There is such a code:

```
class A {
  public $ public_field = 1;
  protected $ protected_field = 2;
  private $ private_field = 3;
}
$a = new A();
$stop = 1;
```

I put a stop on the line

```
$stop = 1;
```

And in my IDE (I have PhpStorm) I see the fields of the object $a:
[image]

Can I somehow find out which of them is public, which is private, which is protected?

Answer (score 0):

You can view Class members' access modifier in **Structure Window**.

On Windows:
Press `Alt + 7` to open **Structure Window** on your left.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYSnb.jpg)

OR press `Ctrl + F12` to open as pop-up.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0014y.jpg)

More about **Structure Window** [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html)

Members' access modifiers are not mentioned in [their](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-code.html) [helps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debug-tool-window-variables.html) so I suppose it's not possible to do view them from **Watch Window**. Unless someone makes a plugin for that.